# selinux context for multiple databases

Tags: postgresql, selinux, mariadb, database-administration, neo4j

I have a directory /media/databases under which I want to hold 3 different databases : mariadb, postgresql and neo4j.

My issue is that I already have configured postgresql selinux context and the server won't start unless the /media/databases context is set on postgresql_db_t.

So my question is : how could I set those contexts right ? Are there some contexts neutral enough to hold ? I've done a :

```
seinfo -t
```

The list is quite large..

Or maybe I am seeing this all wrong and I should only separate my databases at the media root : /media/postgresql, /media/mariadb, /media/neo4j ?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I suspect this will be a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/a/809364/126632

Comment: Nice catch ! Yes it was : I set the directory to unlabeled_t and make a special rule for postgresql with audit2allow. I need to see what happens now for the other db but that should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Each database type directory under /media/databases should have a selinux context set (`semanage fcontext`) matching the rules expected for that database type.

e.g. for MySQL based on [mysql selinux ref](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql):

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/media/mariadb(/.*)?"
# restorecon -Rv /media/mariadb
```